# How can I flag an off-topic post?

Tags: support, flagging, best-practices

How do I flag posts for being off topic?

There isn't any option for that when I try to flag a post. Is it appropriate to use the custom flagging option (I think it is the moderator intervention one..)? I ask because similar post here on Meta seem to indicate that this is an option that appears for them.

Comment: You could just vote to close…

Comment: @JonCuster The vote-to-close privilege isn't available to users with less than 3k reputation.

Comment: If the question is really bad, flag as 'very low quality.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image: Flag menu screenshot]

When you click "flag," you (currently) see a screen like the one shown above.  Choosing "needs improvement" ("the question can't be answered or belongs elsewhere") gives you the same off-topic options that are available to users who have the "vote to close" privilege.